# Vuex Re-render of v-for with Deep change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When using Vuex with Arrays of Objects a v-for doesn't update as expected

The watch method reacts to a mapped Getter change but the v-for element is not updated.

Is there a way to force a rerender from the watch function?

Comment: Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Do you tried once?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Vue.set` or `[yourArray].splice` as shown in the caveats here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: This is the new link btw: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list#Caveats

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a computed property based on watched variable and loop over it.